# Como pegar nas cordenadas pegando a linha e alterando a colunda

Tags: vba, excel-vba

```
   Set rgFound = Range("B1:B1000").Find(Sheets("FormAluguer").Range("E10"))
If rgFound Is Nothing Then
    resposta = MsgBox("Não encontrado.", vbYesNo + vbExclamation, "stock incorrecto")
Else
Dim mrange As String
Dim linha As Integer


mrange = rgFound.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False, External:=False)
 resposta = MsgBox("Foi encontrado em :" + rgFound.Row, vbYesNo + vbExclamation, "stock incorrecto")

End If
```

> mrange retorna $b7 e eu queria pegar neste valor e reter o numero da
>   linha neste caso 7 para depois fazer contas na coluna O linha 7 fazer
>   contas

tentei rgFound.Address().row mas não funciona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema estava no operador de concatenar

> resposta = MsgBox("Foi encontrado em :" + rgFound.Row, vbYesNo +
>   vbExclamation, "stock incorrecto")

deve ser assim:

> resposta = MsgBox("Foi encontrado em :" & rgFound.Row, vbYesNo +
>   vbExclamation, "stock incorrecto")